# Chrome: why does serviceWorker.ready resolve to a service worker registration in "installed" state?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

In Chrome (but not Firefox) the following code resolves to a service worker registration with state `installed`, instead of `activated`, as expected:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(r) {
  console.log("STATE", r.active.state); // outputs "installed" on first load
});
navigator.serviceWorker.register('empty.js').then(function(r) {
  console.log('empty.js registered with scope:', r.scope);
});
```

This seems both contrary to [the spec](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#navigator-service-worker-ready) ("it waits until the promise resolves with a service worker registration that has an active worker") and the [intention of the feature](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/223).

1. Why does this happen? (And why only in Chrome, and not Firefox?)
2. How can I ensure that a some particular set of network requests issued on the host page (e.g. via a `fetch()`) go out via a service worker?

Comment: These discussions might help: https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/issues/170 and https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/799.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is [a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=589494)--the state should actually be `activated` as expected (or `activating`, in which case functional events are queued).